# CN1 stop() method not working every time when issuing Rest API call

Tags: codenameone

Is it sensible to use the stop() method to issue a rest api call, and send data up to the cloud (which may take 0.1s-5s based on connectivity)?

```
requestBuilder.acceptJson().body(jsonDataBody).getAsJsonMap()
```

I ask, as i can consistently reproduce an issue on the simulator where no data is being sent when i close the app, but it goes if i call the same process via a button. On real devices it seems to work fine, but i am getting occasional customer feedback that it isn't always working, ie. data isn't being sent to the cloud (tho no errors). I cannot reproduce it using my own real devices.

I'm having to code blind and just force it by putting in a new async rest call when i do screen navigation, which does the same as stop() except uses this method

```
requestBuilder.acceptJson().body(jsonDataBody).fetchAsJsonMap()
```

Background:
I have my data in a cloud database, fronted by Rest APi's. My app uses storage to store the datetime of when the last upload and download of data was. When i open my app, via start(), it issues a rest call and gets all data, with a datetime stamp > last download datetime. when i close my app i issue another call, via stop(), to send all data locally changed since the last upload datetime, to the cloud. Each record has a lastUpdateDatetime entity property.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's problematic due to two reasons. First the simpler case:

- OS's can invoke `stop()`/`start()` quickly so you're app will stop and start almost immediately and this might trigger data corruption if you don't guard against it
- The worse problem is that if an operation takes a bit longer some OS's might kill it. You can use background fetch to perform downloads/uploads while your app isn't running and that would solve the technical problem here

Personally, I would just send data on change. If change it too rapid I'd add a time threshold for sending but send during the app running and not on `stop()`. Notice that on the device the situation is far more complex as it can suddenly decide to kill the app to make room for the phone app or another critical app. You need to program defensively and try to avoid assumptions where possible.

Comment: Ah ok. This goes against other websites i've read on approach to sync'ing with a server, tho i understand what you are saying and hence why some of my customers experience problems while others don't.I used to have the record upload and download sync only on page entry and on record change, but this led to slower navigation and sometimes freezes when the network was slow or down.  So i think the solution is to do as per main comment and upload data on page navigation async (and hide network errors) and download on app entry start() only. Hope this sounds ok. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: There's a very delicate balance here. Think about it this way, if the app or device crashes in the middle of usage you wouldn't want to lose all your changes. So sending them while the app is running is important. But doing it instantly or over the EDT is wrong as it will impact performance. One of the cool things we have is the EDT idle callback `callSeriallyOnIdle` you can use that to run when the EDT isn't doing anything (no animations etc) you can then invoke an asynchronous API to upload the data to the server. This shouldn't impact runtime performance in any way.

Comment: That’s the way I’ll go. And early customer feedback is that the data is sync’ing now, since taking it off stop(). Thanks